# Is there any way to set a property/attribute for some/all "sub"-Items?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a QML `Pane` with a twenty-some buttons, and I'd like to set their label's `anchors.horizontalCenter`, `anchors.verticalCenter`, and `sourceSize.width` properties (attributes?) in one single place. Is this possible?

In other words, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Pane {
    AllButtons: SetThoseProperties {
        label.sourceSize.width: 32
        label.anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        label.anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
    Button {
        id: button1
        // maybe some reference to the AllButtons thing?
        label: Image {
            source: "qrc:/image1.svg"
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: button1
        // maybe some reference to the AllButtons thing?
        label: Image {
            source: "qrc:/image1.svg"
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

instead of:

```
Pane {
    AllButtons: SetThoseProperties {
        label.sourceSize.width: 32
        label.anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        label.anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
    Button {
        id: button1
        // maybe some reference to the AllButtons thing?
        label: Image {
            source: "qrc:/image1.svg"
            sourceSize.width: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: button2
        // maybe some reference to the AllButtons thing?
        label: Image {
            source: "qrc:/image2.svg"
            sourceSize.width: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new QML component together with its predefined properties, then you can use it as a standalone type.

You can easily do it by right-clicking on an existing object and from refactoring -> move component into separate file.

```
// CustomButton.qml
Button {
    property alias image: bImage.source
    label: Image {
        id: bImage
        source: "qrc:/image2.svg"
        sourceSize.width: 20
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
CustomButton {
   image: "qrc:/image2.svg"
}
```

Also, you could take advantage of repeaters:

```
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: 10
        CustomButton {
            image: "qrc:/image" + index + ".svg"
            onClicked: foos[index]()
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a column of 10 buttons, each with image source corresponding to its index. You can assign the functionality of each button to an array of functions.

With a repeater, you can also avoid using the extra `CustomButton.qml` type, the repeater will repeat whatever object is in its body, so you can define the properties for an object once and those will be applied to all instances.

You can go even further if you specify a `ListModel`, then you can have unique custom properties for each model item besides an index.

Lastly, if you want to easily override the properties for multiple objects, instead of referencing the property value directly use another property for a proxy:

```
// for example in main.qml
property int imageWidth: 20

// CustomButton.qml
...
sourceSize.width: imageWidth
...
```

This way changing `imageWidth` will chance every `sourceSize.width` which references it.